# fetched data using useEffect() which should act as component did mount but data is not getting displayed on web page

Tags: reactjs, fetch

- In use effect the data is empty
- When we do console.log outside use Effect the data is there

How do I solve this problem any help is appreciated

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function RestDetails() {
  const [restaurant,setRestaurant]=useState({});

  let {rName}= useParams();
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(`http://localhost:8089/restaurant/details/${rName}`,{method:'GET'})
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{setRestaurant(data.data);console.log("the value",restaurant)})
  },[])
console.log(restaurant)
```

I tried to give restaurant in dependencies but the call is going for infinite no. of times

when I use restaurant data it is not showing data on web page[image]

this is the code to display  in webpage

`````
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';



return (
    <>
        <div className="header">
            <span className="logo">e!</span>
            <span className="right"> <button className="button1">Login</button>
                <button className="button2">Create an account</button></span>

        </div>
    <div className='photo'><img src={restaurant.thumb} alt="not found" height="350px" width="100%"/></div>
    <div className='rsName'>{restaurant.name}</div>
    
    <div>
    <Tabs>
    <TabList>
      <Tab>Overview</Tab>
      <Tab>Contact</Tab>
    </TabList>

    <TabPanel>
      <div>About this place</div>
      <div>Cuisine</div>
      {/* {cuisineList} */}
      <div>Average Cost</div>
      <div>&#8377; {restaurant.cost}</div>
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel>
      <div>Phone Number</div>
      <div>+91 -123456789</div>
      <div> {restaurant.name} </div>
      <div>{restaurant.address}</div>
    </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
    
    
    </>
  )````
`````

Comment: The console log in the use effect is using the current value of restaurant on initial run which is empty (setRestaurant hasn't set the value yet). Outside you will see the restaurant data once it is set as the component rerenders. Adding restaurant as the dependancy causes the infinite loop because when restaurant is set it causes the fetch and set to run again, this then triggers the useEffect to run again

Comment: so How do I solve this problem

Comment: Can you explain your problem? This is how state works in react so there isn't really a problem. If you need the data in the last `.then` you can just use `data`. Outside the useEffect you can use `restaurant`

Comment: I used the data which was  inside restaurant but it is not showing the output in the web page

Comment: I have attached the  screenshot of what happens when I use the data inside restaurant  it does not shows in web page.

Comment: What's the problem? The `console.log` inside the `useEffect` will always be an empty object, as p7dxb explained to you. Your screenshot shows that the data were correctly set. If it's not displayed, then the problem is not from this part of the code.

Comment: Yes I understood that setState does not work synchronously , my next question is that why it is not displaying on web page

Comment: I have attached the code of webpage where I am using the value of restaurant state is there any thing wrong  in this I have imported all the necessary things

Comment: The title and description of your question does not correspond to the problem you want to solve.

Comment: But really, just read your data and code more carefully...

Comment: I am getting data through fetch but while using the data for web page it is not getting displayed  and the thing is I cannot ask more questions as stack overflow does not allow to do so